# RadCartesianChart didn't drawn because of null values for some points

Tags: windows-8, charts, telerik, windows-8.1, radchart

I use Telerik RadCartesianChart, Its ItemSource binding on ObservableCollection.

For example it has 3 Items:

Value 1 = 10

Value 2 = null

value 3 = 20

Its StrokeMode ="AllButPlotLine" ,

The line didn't drawn because of the null value.
Can I draw it?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

RadChart (RadCartesianChart) supports empty (null/NaN) values. Here is an example using the MVVM pattern for you to explore. Please note that there is no Value represented for Oranges.

> There is also an example of Empty Values in your installation folder found here : C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Windows 8.1 XAML Q2 2014\Demos\Examples\Chart\EmptyValues

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <chart:RadCartesianChart Width="700" Height="700">
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                <chart:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="XY" StripLinesVisibility="Y">
                    <chart:CartesianChartGrid.MajorXLineStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#B45121"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="4,2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </chart:CartesianChartGrid.MajorXLineStyle>
                    <chart:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#58622D"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="10,2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </chart:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
                </chart:CartesianChartGrid>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.DataContext>
                <local:ViewModel/>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.DataContext>
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <chart:CategoricalAxis/>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <chart:LinearAxis/>
            </chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <chart:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding SeriesData}">
                <chart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
                    <chart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Category"/>
                </chart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
                <chart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
                    <chart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                </chart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
            </chart:LineSeries>
        </chart:RadCartesianChart>
    </Grid>
```

CustomPoint.cs file

```
public class CustomPoint
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.SeriesData = new List<CustomPoint>()
        {
            new CustomPoint{ Category = "Apples", Value = 10 },
            new CustomPoint{ Category = "Oranges"},
            new CustomPoint{ Category = "Pears", Value = 15 },
        };
    }
    public List<CustomPoint> SeriesData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The line represent the values didn't drawn .. because no value for oranges in you example. Was it drawn with you?